# Trait object discrepancy between Vec and HashMap

Tags: rust, traits, trait-objects

I've been struggling to understand why the following code behaves the way it does ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4ca0cb47093fc14149e4ecb1031550e6)):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait Trait<'a> {
    fn get_enum(&'a self) -> Enum<'a>;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
enum Enum<'a> {
    Arr(Vec<&'a dyn Trait<'a>>),
    Map(HashMap<String, &'a dyn Trait<'a>>)
}

impl<'a> Trait<'a> for Enum<'a> {
    fn get_enum(&'a self) -> Enum<'a> {
        self.clone()
    }
}

fn process<'a>(val: &'a dyn Trait<'a>) -> Vec<&'a dyn Trait<'a>> {
    let mut traits: Vec<&dyn Trait> = vec![];
    match val.get_enum() {
        Enum::Arr(v) => {
            for elem in v {
                traits.push(elem);
            }
        },
        Enum::Map(m) => {
            for elem in m.values() {
                traits.push(elem);
            }
        }
    }
    traits
}
```

This throws the error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&dyn Trait<'_>: Trait<'_>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:29:29
   |
29 |                 traits.push(elem);
   |                             ^^^^ the trait `Trait<'_>` is not implemented for `&dyn Trait<'_>`
   |
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn Trait<'_>`
```

The thing that's strange to me isn't exactly the error as much as the fact that the error only shows up listing values from the `HashMap` and not from `Vec`'s iterator. Can someone explain to me:

1. Why the two structures' iterators behave so differently
2. How I can pass values from my map into my array

I have found the same phenomenon occurs retrieving any value via the `get` call as well.

Comment: `for elem in m.values()` takes `m` by reference and iterates over references. `for elem in v` takes `v` by value and iterates over values. If you write `for elem in &v` both fail, and if you write `for (_, elem) in m` both pass.

Comment: @trentcl how about making this an answer?

Comment: I'm mostly trying to find some way of calling `get` to push into the vector. I also understand the difference in iterators but am having a hard time understanding their implication on the trait object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is not between `Vec` and `HashMap`, but in how you iterate over them. `for` loops use `IntoIterator` internally (see [Why is iterating over a collection via `for` loop considered a "move" in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123462/why-is-iterating-over-a-collection-via-for-loop-considered-a-move-in-rust)), so the type of `elem` depends on the iterable.

```
for elem in v {
    traits.push(elem);
}
```

`Vec<T>` implements `IntoIterator<Item = T>`, so inside the loop `elem` is `&'a dyn Trait<'a>`.

```
for elem in m.values() {
    traits.push(elem);
}
```

`HashMap<_, T>::values` borrows `self` to create an `Iterator<Item = &T>` (which implements `IntoIterator<Item = &T>`). Since the value type of `m` is a reference already, inside the loop `elem` is something like `&'b &'a dyn Trait<'a>` (where `'b` is the lifetime of the borrow of `m`).

The reason you get the error `` the trait bound `&dyn Trait<'_>: Trait<'_>` is not satisfied `` is because the compiler is trying to *coerce* `&'b &'a dyn Trait` to `&'b dyn Trait`, but it can't because `&'a dyn Trait` does not implement `Trait`. But even if it did that would not solve the problem -- you would just get a borrowing error instead when you tried to return references of lifetime `'b` from the function.

> How I can pass values from my map into my array?

I mentioned in the comments that you can iterate over `m` by value, which is similar to what you're doing with `v`:

```
for (_key, elem) in m {
    traits.push(elem);
}
```

This is destructive iteration because you can't use `m` afterwards. Another option, since shared references implement `Copy`, is to copy them out of the map as you iterate over it:

```
for elem in m.values() {
    traits.push(*elem);          // using * to dereference
}
```

or

```
for &elem in m.values() {        // using & to destructure
    traits.push(elem);
}
```

These loops do the same thing; the only difference is the type of `elem`.