# Does a Rust for-in (for-of) loop cause reassignment of a container?

Tags: rust

Consider the following for-in loop in Rust, which moves the non-privative data type `String`.

```
let strings: Vec<String> = something;
for s in strings {
    // uses `s`
}
```

Since a String is not a bitwise trivially copyable datatype, the elements of `strings` are moved, one by one, into `s` and then dropped at the end of the block defined by `{` and `}`.

##### After each iteration, what does the `Vec` object look like?

Imaging that `strings` is initialized to contain this:

```
[ "hello", "world", "final string" ]
```

After 1 iteration of the loop, the element `"hello"` has been moved.

We cannot have a `Vec` now looking like this

```
[ None, "world", "final string" ]
```

because `None` is not a `String`.

This means the `Vec` must now be shorter:

```
[ "world", "final string" ]
```

Since `"hello"` was removed from the front of the `Vec` this strongly suggests to me that a re-allocation has taken place.

**If this is not the case, then why does no re-allocation occur.**

AFAIK `Vec` does not contain something like an offset to the first element in memory, like a C++ `std::deque` would. So it seem to me that Rust `Vec` cannot avoid a re-allocation when the first element is moved.

Finally, assuming I have understood all of the above, which may not be the case, does this mean that iterating over a `Vec` containing not-copyable objects is *slow* ?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59123462

Comment: @mkrieger1 This example comes directly from Programming Rust (O'Reilly).... Good point. Not sure if their example is invalid Rust code? It raises a slightly different question about how is it possible to iterate over this `Vec`.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR**: It doesn't matter.

Once you started iterating over the `Vec`, you moved it and you cannot access it anymore, so it doesn't matter what its internal state is.

If you are asking about the implementation, then the `Vec` itself doesn't change. [The iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.IntoIter.html) holds a pointer to the beginning of the `Vec` (to free its memory at the end) and to the next and last elements. The elements already iterated over are just discarded, without their memory physically overwritten.

Comment: The `Vec` isn't mutable @ChayimFriedman - So that's not quite it.  I think it has more to do with the interaction of `for - in` and the `IntoIterator` trait.

Comment: Is this were the case the `Iterator` would be required in order to free the memory... And I don't think that makes sense?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Once a thing is moved, it doesn't matter if it was declared mutable or not. Also, the iterator is mutated, not the `Vec`.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Why don't you think it makes sense?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Coming from C++, it would be weird if a destructor call required an iterator as an argument. Maybe I misunderstood what you intended to say?

Comment: It would also be weird if an iterator was a member of a container class, hence imposing the constraint that there can only be one iterator per class object.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant The destructor or the container doesn't require an iterator, the iterator's destructor needs to free the items, which may involve calling the container destructor (but likely not). And I don't understand why you think there can be only one iterator per container (there is only one `IntoIterator` implementation, but there can be multiple applicable iterators).

Comment: Note that for the specific case of `Vec<String>`, each iteration deallocates one string buffer. The vector itself is only deallocated at the very end as one block.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, but this is done by the consumer code (although if the loop is `break`ed the iterator will free the remaining `String`s).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman If there is an iterator which exists, and that iterator stores information about "how far along a container it has iterated", then that information would be required to free the memory of the container, if the act of iterating moves elements of the container. Does that make sense?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Yes, true, that's why it stores this information. What is the question?

Comment: Then the containers destructor requires information about how far the iterator has iterated. Otherwise, it doesn't know which elements to free and which elements to not double-free.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant But once you started iterating, you moved the container and it's destructor won't be called. It's the iterator's destructor whose job is to free the elements now.

Comment: TIL - Even if non-mut, you can still move/consume a variable, not just copy or borrow it.  That's really backwards IMO, but hey, it's probably widespread.  That's just really unexpected, since `const` really means it in C++ (yes I know about the `mutable` keyword, exceptions to the rule aside I mean).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman That's still very strange as it implies transfer of ownership from a container to an iterator. While I don't disagree, that is something that seems possible, it also seems... weird

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant This is how Rust works with moves, and it is also usually how C++ works with move (C++ just doesn't have moving iterators because it doesn't need them).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman How would you write something equivalent in C++? I can't see a way of doing that

Answer (score 0):

The `for item in container {}` syntax implicitly calls `container.into_iter()`, which consumes `container`, and transfers ownership of its contents into the `IntoIterator` object.

On each iteration of the `for` loop, the `IntoIterator` a String is processed and then dropped.

Here's an example that explicitly calls `into_iter()` and has explicit type annotations to more clearly demonstrate what's happening:

```rust
fn main() {
    let container: Vec<String> = vec!["Hello".to_string(), "World".to_string()];

    {
        let iterator: std::vec::IntoIter<String> = container.into_iter(); // consumes `container`

        // Now `iterator` owns the items that were in `container`.
        // dbg!(container);  // error[E0382]: use of moved value: `container`
        for item in iterator {
            println!("item: {item}");
        }
        // ^^ The iterator will be dropped after the for loop.
    }
}
```

[Rust Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba316fb6336bfec202604e9f6e147400)

Comment: I would change the wording saying "transfers ownership [...] until the `for` loop is done.", because ownership is actually transferred into the `for` loop and never returned back; You cannot get `iterator` back, and the strings are actually dropped on each loop, and the iterator right after the `for` loop ends, not at the end of scope like you said.

Comment: Ok that's interesting, but still raises questions about how the memory for each element is managed internally. If there is an iterator object which takes ownership of the memory managed by the original container, this suggests to me that one vector like datastructure is being transformed into something else like a deque. (Double ended queue, maybe even something with links in it like a list.) It just seems slightly suspicious to me that something that can only have `push`, `pop` behaviour suddenly becomes something with `pop_front` behaviour.